# Array indexing using "sed"

Tags: shell-script, sed, array, associative-array

I am working on one shell script which search directory modified in last 24 hours and then compress them using tar.

**Folder Search :**

```
find /path to log directory/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +0
```

*example output:*

```
/path to log directory/01_05_2016
/path to log directory/02_05_2016
/path to log directory/03_05_2016
/path to log directory/04_05_2016
```

**Truncate unnecessary character:**

```
find /path to log directory/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +0 | tr -d "_" | tr -d "path to log directory"
```

*example output:*

```
01052016 02052016 03052016 04052016
```

**Separate the truncated strings as individual array element using "sed":**

```
# Folder search

declare -a array="($(find <0-24 hour directory serach> | <truncate uncecessary character> | sed 's/\([0-9]*\).*/[\1]="\1"/'))"

# Array Printing
echo "Number of Array Elements: "${#array[@]}
echo "array[01052016]: " ${array[01052016]}
echo "array[02052016]: " ${array[02052016]}
echo "array[03052016]: " ${array[03052016]}
echo "array[04052016]: " ${array[04052016]}
```

*example output*

```
Number of Array Elements: 4
array[01052016]: 01052016
array[02052016]: 02052016
array[03052016]: 03052016
array[04052016]: 04052016
```

**Compress the output:**

```
LOG_DIR_NAME='<find folder>'

xargs tar -cvzPf /ouput folder/logname.tar.gz  /path to log directory $LOG_DIR_NAME
```

**Problem Statment:**

By the use of sed command, I can separate the search string into an individual array element. With the use of this command

```
sed 's/\([0-9]*\).*/[\1]="\1"/'
```

where [\1] defines my array index and "\1" defines my element.

**Desired Output**
I am interested in getting the array element stored from index (0 to n)

```
array[0]: 01052016
array[1]: 02052016
array[2]: 03052016
array[3]: 04052016
```

How can I customize the array indexing in this case or traverse thru the array without knowing the start index?

Please help

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should simplify your command to:

```
$ find "/path to log directory/" -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +0 | sed 's#.*/##; s#_##g' 
01052016
03052016
04052016
02052016
```

Next, to save as an array, you could just do:

```
array=( $(find "/path to log directory/" -maxdepth 1 -type d -mtime +0 | sed 's#.*/##; s#_##g') )
```

That saves it as you want, in an array with numerical, increasing indices starting from 0:

```
$ for i in {0..3}; do echo "$i : ${array[$i]}"; done
0 : 01052016
1 : 03052016
2 : 04052016
3 : 02052016
```

---

That said, if you do find yourself needing to iterate over an associative array, you can do that too:

```
$ declare -a array=( "foo"=>"bar" "baz"=>"bad" )
$ for i in ${!array[*]}; do echo "$i : ${array[$i]}"; done
baz : bad
foo : bar
```